# Can't git push files from shared hosting to Github via php shell_exec()

Tags: php, git

I try to push files from my shared hosting with cPanel to Github using the following PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$push = shell_exec('git push -u origin master');

if($push === null) {
  echo "Error executing git push command";
} else {
  echo "<pre>$push</pre>";
}
```

but I get the first echo i.e. *"Error executing git push command"* and don't get any php error to know what's the reason of the problem.

I added and committed files before that via cPanel's Terminal successfully.

And if I run `git push -u origin master` in the Terminal and enter my Github personal token, I can push files successfully too.

The command `git status` is executed in PHP shell_exec() successfully.

Comment: When you run `git push` in the terminal, are you running as the same user that PHP is running as?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I upload php file via cPanel "Files manager" as the same user that in the Terminal and then run it via browser address bar. Gemini just said that the problem "is likely due to missing authentication information within the shell_exec call" and gave me command `git push -u origin master --token {$token}` but it doesn't help

Comment: Everything runs as a user. On your local machine it is you, possibly `stkuser`. If you SSH into something, you are that user, maybe `stkuser` but maybe `www-user` or someone else. If you run a PHP command via the terminal, it will be run as your current user. When you access a PHP page in your browser, that's another user. If you are using PHP-FPM, this is usually configured in a location such as `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, replacing the version and filename appropriately. Git tokens are stored in your user folder, and users don't share these folders